# Kali linux WiFi not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a windows 10 with Intel ac 3160 wireless 
And I am running kali linux 2.0 in vm ware and it does not show Bluetooth option but not wireless options 
I am new to Linux plz help

Comment: Your wording is a bit confusing.  "it does not show Bluetooth option but not wireless options".  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the WiFi connection to be available to the Kali host, just set the virtual network of the virtual machine (VM) connected through NAT.

But odds are you want to use Kali auditing tools to test WiFi networks. Kali in a VM needs a WiFi dongle in order for VMWare to be able to virtually connect it to the OS host. Then, Linux will "see" your dongle as connected to the VM and will be able to load the proper drivers for it. That done, your VM has WiFi, and Linux (and the auditing tools) will be able to use it to get packets, etc.

When you connect hardware to a guest VM, you need to disconnect it from the host (your real box) and that's a hard thing to do (you need to know how the host driver works and build an interface to the virtual device). USB simplifies things, because you "only" have to disconnect it from the host (as you would usually do by hand) and make a generic interface that virtually make it appear as connected to the VM. Then, is up to the guest OS.

I think Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 is internal: that's why VMWare cannot connect it to the VM.